# ¿Que pasa cuando se instacia una clase en java?

Tags: java

Soy principiante en POO y tengo entendido que cuando instanciamos una clase se crea un objeto y este adquiere los atributos de su clase y los almacena en un espacio de memoria, pero que pasa con los métodos de la clase ¿También se almacenan en el espacio creado para ese objeto?.

Comment: ¿qué has intentado?¿Cuál es el problema con el que te encontraste?

Comment: No me queda clara tu pregunta. Si es sobre los métodos, sería un consumo innecesario de memoria si cada instancia almacenara sus métodos en ella. Después de todo es un paradigma de programación y no dejan de ser funciones. Probablemente cada clase cargue sus métodos en memoria y varíe algunas cosas de acuerdo a la instancia que quiera usarlo, como la referencia this.

Comment: Una clase no es más que una receta, no tiene valor, no tiene acciones (normalmente/simplificando), es simplemente una guía de cómo convertirse en algo. Un objeto es algo. La clase es la receta de un pastel, no es más que un papel con instrucciones. ¡El Objeto es el pastel en sí mismo, sabroso y listo para ser comido! La clase toma algo de memoria, pero solo un poco, ya que son solo un montón de instrucciones.
El objeto usa mucha más memoria ya que tiene sus valores adentro, cada valor, cada variable usará algo de memoria cuando esté lleno de información. Los métodos no usan mucha memoria, desp